# I can't choose the "first message" in a group of selected emails (in Mail.app) using Applescript…

Tags: email, applescript

So I can iterate through a group of emails to using:

```
repeat with eachMessage in emailSelection
        log content of eachMessage
        set theContent to content of eachMessage
    end repeat
```

Yet when I try to arbitrarily select one, say the first one in the set, I get an error

```
        set newContent to content of first message in emailSelection
```

returns:

> (*Can’t get message 1 of {message id 740166 of mailbox "INBOX" of account "IMAP PL" of application "Mail", message id 740165 of mailbox "INBOX" of account "IMAP PL" of application "Mail", message id 739792 of mailbox "INBOX" of account "IMAP PL" of application "Mail", message id 740164 of mailbox "INBOX" of account "IMAP PL" of application "Mail", message id 738259 of mailbox "INBOX" of account "IMAP PL" of application "Mail", message id 738258 of mailbox "INBOX" of account "IMAP PL" of application "Mail", message id 738257 of mailbox "INBOX" of account "IMAP PL" of application "Mail"}.*)

I want to select the first *object in the set of emails* but it seems to be trying to identify an email message id of "1" which obviously is not included in the set of selected emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference emailSelection as a list using the `item` keyword.

eg,

```
set newContent to content of (item 1 of emailSelection)
```

or

```
set newContent to content of (the first item of emailSelection)
```

Comment: Ha, yes that's what i love about AppleScript, it's a bit like conversation, still waiting for the "Manners" add-on though. 'please can you copy this_variable to the clipboard?'